# Gnome Software is eating RAM even when inactive

Tags: gnome, ram, gnome-software

It's closed, but there is probably some daemon waiting for the updates. Why it's even there? And why so much RAM?

[image]

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1616332

Comment: To answer your "Why it's even there?" question: GNOME Software auto-starts at system startup by default. You might want to [disable that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959353/disable-gnome-software-from-loading-at-startup).